# Office addin (custom functions) deployment to Azure app service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

Using "yo office" generated the custom functions add-in project. Implemented all the necessary custom functions and the addin works fine in local environment.

Now facing following deployment issue when deploying to Azure services.

> Invalid start-up command "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml" in package.json. Please use the format "node ".
> Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
> Invalid start-up command "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml" in package.json. Please use the format "node ".\r\nMissing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\92.30310.5111\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Following is the script block in package.json

```
scripts": {
"build": "webpack -p --mode production --https false",
"build:dev": "webpack --mode development --https false",
"build-dev": "webpack --mode development --https false && echo . && echo . && echo . && echo Please use 'build:dev' instead of 'build-dev'.",
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
"prod-server": "webpack-dev-server --mode production",
"start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
"start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
"start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
"stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
"validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
"watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
"configure-sso": "office-addin-sso configure manifest.xml"}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: That is the same set of errors that I got, when I forgot to run "npm install" after creating the addin using yo office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the code base. Used express and webpack for deploying to the servers. Tested in both Azure and AWS. Application is up and running.

By following https://binyamin.medium.com/creating-a-node-express-webpack-app-with-dev-and-prod-builds-a4962ce51334 able to resolve the deployment issues